# How do i get my program to display a noise that the animal makes if the input a dog, cat or bird

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
name = input("What is your pet's name?")
species = input("What type of pet is it?")
age = input("How old is your pet?")

class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, species, age, noise):
        self.name = name
        self.species = species
        self.age = age
        self.noise = noise

    def setNoise(self, noise):
            self.noise = "WOOF"
        elif species == cat:
            self.noise = "MEOW!"
        elif species == bird:
            self.noise = "CAWW!"
        else:
            self.noise = "Animal Noise"

    def get_type(self):
        print("Pet")

    def toString(self):
        return"{} is a {} and is {} years old".format(self.name,self.species,self.age,self.noise)

myPet = Pet(name,species,age,noise)
print(noise, myPet.toString())
```

i cannot figure out how to make my program display a noise when i type a certain animal in it, such as a dog, cat, or bird. any help would be amazing. I keep running into the error that noise is not defined. also when i try to use my species input to check if it equals dog it errors out.

Comment: I think you're trying to print `myPet.noise`.

Comment: I'll do you a favor and remove all those pointless setters and getters. Not only are they irrelevant to the question, but they're not needed (or wanted) in python at all.

Comment: You also appear to be missing an `if` in `setNoise`, and you don't use the `noise` argument, just the species, so that function doesn't seem needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be what you're trying to get. You used the `cat`, `bird`, etc. variables without defining them. I assume these should be strings. I also got rid of the `setNoise` function which didn't seem to have a purpose. Since the noise is based on the species, I set it at `__init__`. Python also has a special method called `__str__`. If you set this, then when I call `print(myPet)` it will print the return value of `myPet.__str__()`. This is better to use than defining your own string method because it gets called automatically when printing.

```py
name = input("What is your pet's name?")
species = input("What type of pet is it?")
age = input("How old is your pet?")
# you might want to set age = int(age) if age is, e.g., an integer number of years

class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, species, age):
        self.name = name
        self.species = species
        self.age = age

        if species == "dog":
            self.noise = "WOOF"
        elif species == "cat":
            self.noise = "MEOW!"
        elif species == "bird":
            self.noise = "CAWW!"
        else:
            self.noise = "Animal Noise"

    def get_type(self):
        print("Pet")

    def __str__(self):
        return"{} is a {} and is {} years old".format(self.name,self.species,self.age,self.noise)

myPet = Pet(name, species, age)
print(myPet.noise, myPet)
```